# Secure JSON request from .Net to Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, encryption

I'm sending a JSON result back to a javascript (Jquery) on my IIS/MVC4 website. 
The json contains a string value of around 60-100 letters.

Currently it is being sent in clear text with no encyption at all.

What would be the simplest method to encrypt just this message between the javascript client and the .net C# backend?

The encryption dosent have to be superb, but just enough that you cant figure/bruteforce out the contents in under 1 hour.

Keep in mind that everyone has the javascript so I cant just use a common key for all clients.

I was thinking something along the line of an RSA encryption where the client generates a keypair and sends its public key back with the request and the server uses this to encrypt the value.. I cant find any examples of this though so I'm very open to suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the entire webpage over SSL (HTTPS). The server and browser will take care of encryption for you.

Comment: Would that require me to get a SSL certificate to avoid warnings on the client?

Comment: Yes, it would. (This is a cheaper option then doing all the work needed to get something not-as-good as SSL though).

Comment: Was hoping I could avoid doing the whole page in HTTPS and buying a certificate for this.. but it might be the only good option it seems